# reordering factor levels in ggplot2 doesn't fit the y geom_text annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem in ggplot2. If I reorder factor levels and I plot the text labels value (in this case frequency), the text label values still remains in the old levels.
What's wrong????
[image]

29 and 71 are the frequencies but I want to be fitted 29 to the green line and 71 to the red line. If you reverse the plot, numbers fits well!
Thaaanks
Here the code of the graph:

```
with(data4,
     ggplot(subset(data4,ASSAGGIATORE=="Manera"),
            aes(ASSAGGIATORE,Freq,fill=SCELTA)) +
       geom_bar() +  
       geom_text(aes(label=round(Freq)),
                 position="stack") + 
       scale_size(range=c(5,6)) +                   
       geom_hline(aes(yintercept=mediana),
                  colour="navy",
                  linetype="dotted") + 
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("chartreuse3","brown1"),
                         name="RISPOSTE",
                         labels=c("% Risposte Corrette","% Risposte Sbagliate")) +
       geom_text(aes(1,
                     mediana,
                     label="Assaggiatore Medio",
                     vjust=0),
                 size=4,
                 colour="navy") + 
       scale_y_continuous('% Totale Assaggi'))
```

here the example of data4

```
SCELTA   ASSAGGIATORE    Freq     Mediana
no       Manera          28.57143 63.33333
si       Manera          71.42857 63.33333
```

I think I got the solution:

```
ggplot(subset(data4,ASSAGGIATORE=="Manera"),
   aes(ASSAGGIATORE,Freq,fill=SCELTA),label=Freq)+geom_bar()+
      stat_bin(geom="text", aes(position='stack', label=Freq,))
```

Comment: Could we have access to `data4`?

Comment: There is no reason to use `with` when using `ggplot` since there is something like an implicit `with` already built in.  I'd suggest getting rid of a bunch of your formatting and extra geoms and starting with the most basic plot that reproduces the issue.  Finally, please provide data so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I tried also with another solution that works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(subset(data4,ASSAGGIATORE=="Manera"),
  aes(ASSAGGIATORE,Freq,fill=SCELTA),label=Freq)+geom_bar()+
    stat_bin(geom="text", aes(position='stack', label=Freq,))
```

[image]